# Нужен совет для оформления контрастивного анализа (parte 2)

Tags: общие-вопросы

Друзья, как некоторые из Вас уже поняли, в моей работе сталкиваются итальянский текст и перевод предложений на русский.

Пример:

Итальянское предложение:

*Она едва могла поверить, что она **была** той/что это **была** она самая, которая решилась на подобную авантюру.* (очень грубый дословный перевод)

Русская версия:

*Ей с трудом верилось, что она когда-то решилась на такую авантюру.*

В анализе сопоставляется использование сослагательного наклонения в итальянском и то, какое наклонение используется в переводе на русский. В итальянском предложении глагол ***была*** стоит в сосл. накл. Русский перевод вполне приемлемый, но в нем нет той части с сосл. накл., которая есть в итальянском. Таких примеров попадается небольшое количество и я не найду идею, как лучше отобразить это в анализе? то есть в таблице у меня стоит временная форма итальянского конъюнктива и тип придаточного. Эти же два пункта мне надо указать в графе "русский". В русском я могу только определить тип предложения, но как оформить то, что глагол ***есть*** в итальянском не используется русским переводчиком? Надеюсь, Вы понимаете, что я хочу сказать! Спасибо заранее!!!

Comment: Насколько можно судить из написанного, в оригинале используется сослагательное наклонение. Так? Но, по-моему, здесь изъявительное наклонение. Ведь действие имело место в прошлом?

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы!!! (это я просто перевела глагол прошедшим временем, иначе в русском не получится) Но по нормам романских языков мы используем в таких предложениях сослагательный модус, чтобы передать определённые чувства к выраженному действию.

Comment: А почему бы вам не оставить эту графу пустой, ведь в русском  глагол ''быть" не передан. Можете, в крайнем случае, в соответствующей таблице обозначить пропуск глагола  нулем.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Идея с цифрой ноль мне на самом деле нравится! Сделаю так!!! : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

РАЗМЫШЛЕНИЯ НА ТЕМУ (КАК ПЕРЕВЕСТИ итальянский конъюнктив)

**Дословный перевод**

Она едва могла поверить, что это **была** она самая, которая решилась на подобную авантюру.

**Русская версия**

Ей с трудом верилось, что она когда-то решилась на такую авантюру.

**Другие версии перевода**

(1) Ей с трудом верилось, что это именно она **была** той, которая **когда-то** решилась на такую авантюру.

(2) Ей с трудом верилось, что она **когда-то** **могла** решиться на такую авантюру.

**Комментарий**

В русской версии чувство сомнения передает лексическое значение глагола "верить", но при этом опускается тонкость восприятия итальянского оригинала, а именно идея отождествления себя и той, которая когда-то решилась на авантюру.

В другой редакции чувство сомнения можно усилить модальной формой "могла решиться" или сохранить два придаточных.

**Об итальянском конъюнктиве**

Конъюнктив выражает действие, которое говорящий **воспринимает** как нереальное или **сообщает** о нем, как о нереальном. Эта нереальность может выражаться как сомнение, возможность, желание, неуверенность. Обычно речь идет не об объективной неопределенности, а о неопределенности субъективной, ощущаемой говорящим. Зачастую выбор наклонения зависит от намерений и языковой “чуткости” говорящего, а не только от правил нормативных грамматик.

http://discollection.ru/article/09022008_titova_tat_jana_romanovna_73202/3

Answer (score 0):

В переводе на русский переводчик прибег к т.н. грамматическим трансформациям,  поскольку для русского не свойственна такое форма изложения. К тому же в русском переводе используется изъявительное наклонение.

Comment: дорогой Серж, в том то и делo, что в русском этой части предложения нет! Есть глагол "верить" и глагол "решиться", кот. стоят в обоих языках в изъявительном наклонении, а вот тот "дополнительный" глагол, кот. еще присутствует в итальянском, отсутствует в русском. И я не знаю, как это лаконично запихать в таблицу...